# Supercollider server error " 'localhost' exited with exit code -1073740791."

Tags: supercollider

I keep getting "Server 'localhost' exited with exit code -1073740791." error when running supercollider's servers, on Windows on a Lenovo laptop. I changed the audio interface manually by code but still the same. I don't have any issues with my computer's sound, I re-installed different supercollider versions, tried KillAllServers, and I don't have Jack installed. Please tell me how I can solve this issue. Thanks very much in advance.

My log:

> Requested devices:
> In:
>
> - (default)
>   Out:
> - (default)
>
> Selecting default system input/output devices
>
> Booting with:   In: MME : Microphone Array (AMD Audio Dev   Out: MME :
> Headphones (Realtek(R) Audio) SC_PortAudioDriver: PortAudio failed at
> Pa_OpenStream with error: 'Unanticipated host error' could not
> initialize audio. Server 'localhost' exited with exit code
> -1073740791.

Answer (score 0):

Does your microphone normally work?
Is your input and output running at the same sample rate?

I'm not a windows user, but some googling suggested that running a troubleshooter may help: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/microphone-amd-array-not-working/4c81c607-1377-4233-bcc4-b56205b6b29d

Comment: it was all fine and one day after a windows update it didn't work. I reinstalled the windows and it was fine again, today it stopped working again. I uninstalled all the apps that I had (!) and it's still not working so it's not a compatibility issue. it's either smthing I am missing or it is because I have apps without liscence on my laptop.

Comment: I would figure this out by doing the following:
1. Re-install windows
2. Install SuperCollider and verify it works
3. Get all the system audio settings, as detailed as you can.
4. Re-install one of your other apps.
5. Check if the audio settings have changed.
5. Check if SuperCollider is still working.
6. If SuperCollider still works, goto step 4.
7. If SuperCollider does not work and your audio settings have changed, try changing them back.
8. If that doesn't help, can you live without that application?